# How to implement handsfree bluetooth calling through a non-cellular device/tablet?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So, I want to build my app where I can make a `Bluetooth` calling from a tablet which is non-cellular. I have already made app till pairing devices with the tablet but I can't figure out now for the next step How I can call that device which is paired with my tablet? Anyone has any lead so that I can start work on.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Switch bluetoothSwitch;
    public static Button discoveryBtn;
    public static Button searchBtn;
    public static ListView listView;
    public static ListView pairedListView;
    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> btList;
    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> pairList;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayPairedAdapter;
    public Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    public BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter; // For any Bluetooth activity, BluetoothAdapter is required.
    public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview_new_devices);
        pairedListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btList = new ArrayList<>();
        pairList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayPairedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.device_name);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.device_name);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(deviceListener);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(arrayPairedAdapter);
        if(bluetoothAdapter!=null){
            bluetoothSwitch = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothSwitch);
            discoveryBtn = findViewById(R.id.discovery);
            searchBtn = findViewById(R.id.search);
            bluetoothSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (bluetoothSwitch.isChecked()) {
                        turnOn();
                    } else {
                        turnOff();
                    }
                }
            });

            discoveryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    makeDiscoverable();
                }
            });

            searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    checkPermission();
                }
            });

            mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                        if(device.getBondState()!=BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                            String deviceName = device.getName();
                            String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                            btList.add(device);
                            arrayAdapter.add(deviceName + "\n" + deviceAddress);
                        }
                    }

                    else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                        Log.i("Discovery status:","Finished");
                    }

                    else if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                        final int curr_state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE,BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
                        final int prev_state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE,BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                        if(curr_state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prev_state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Paired",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else if(curr_state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prev_state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unpaired",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }

                }
            };
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

            filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

            filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver,filter);

            // storing the paired devices information
            pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if(pairedDevices.size()>0){
                findViewById(R.id.title_paired).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.listView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for(BluetoothDevice device:pairedDevices){
                    arrayPairedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                    pairList.add(device);
                }
            }
            else{
                arrayPairedAdapter.add("No Devices found!!!");
            }

        }

    }

    public void searchDevices(){ // search for all available devices in the range of the bluetooth

        if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    public void makeDiscoverable(){ // Make a device discoverable to all
        Intent discoverableIntent =
                new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 3000);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }

    public void turnOn(){ // method to turn on the bluetooth
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This device doesn't support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1); // the second argument is for requestCode and it should be greater than 0.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void turnOff(){ // method to turn off the bluetooth
        bluetoothAdapter.disable();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void checkPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1);
        }
        searchDevices();
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener deviceListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); // we should stop the discovery.
            Log.i("In listener","pairing device");
            Log.i("Passing this device to ","pair method");
            btList.get(position).createBond();
            arrayPairedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode){
            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    searchDevices();
                } else {
                    searchDevices();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        arrayAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        // Don't forget to unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver.
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); // It's a big task for bluetooth adapter for discovery process and it will consume lot of resources,
                                            // so, it's safe to cancel this process in onDestroy() lifecycle.
    }
}
```